# update database from datagridview Error

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

I'm having some trouble getting the update button, the error that is displaying is

> "Syntax Error in Update statement"

.

I'm using MS Access for the queries and C# Windows Forms

```
 private void View_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string connectionString = @"String";
            string oleDbquery = @"SELECT Id,Id_Material,Material,LastCounted,Count From Counts where LastCounted = #" + dateCounted.Value.ToShortDateString() + "#";
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            oleDBCommand = new OleDbCommand(oleDbquery, connection);
            oleDBAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(oleDBCommand);
            sBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(oleDBAdapter);
            ds = new DataSet();
            oleDBAdapter.Fill(sDs, "Entires");
            dt = ds.Tables["Entires"];
            connection.Close();
            dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables["Entires"];
            dataGridView2.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
    #endregion

    #region Insert Counts

    private void InsertCount()
    {
        try
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(strConnectionString))
                {
                    using (OleDbCommand oleDbCmd = new OleDbCommand("InsertCounts", connection))
                    {
                        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != null)
                        {
                            connection.Open();
                            oleDbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                            oleDbCmd.Parameters.Add("@Id_Material", OleDbType.Integer, 100).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
                            oleDbCmd.Parameters.Add("@Material", OleDbType.VarChar, 300).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
                            oleDbCmd.Parameters.Add("@LastCounted", OleDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

                            oleDbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            connection.Close();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
        }
    }

    #endregion

    private void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            oleDBAdapter.Update(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

I've have use this method before and it worked, just can't figure it out in this code.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.